# Как подменить User agent на андроиде

Tags: android, google-chrome

Как подменить user agent на фальшивый при каждом открытии браузера chrome ?
Возможно ли это

Comment: С помощью стороннего приложения можно, но нужно иметь рут

Comment: Можно без сторонних программ, но рут всё равно нужен

Comment: Я нашел свой ответ . спасибо !